# adding second child to supervisor throws error

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, erlang-supervisor

I want to add a second child to my supervisor but i get the following error.

** (Mix) Could not start application cloner_worker: exited in: ClonerWorker.Application.start(:normal, [])
** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
** (ArgumentError) The module ClonerWorker.Worker was given as a child to a supervisor but it does not exist.
(elixir 1.11.2) lib/supervisor.ex:631: Supervisor.init_child/1
(elixir 1.11.2) lib/enum.ex:1399: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
(elixir 1.11.2) lib/supervisor.ex:617: Supervisor.init/2
(elixir 1.11.2) lib/supervisor.ex:556: Supervisor.start_link/2
(kernel 7.1) application_master.erl:277: :application_master.start_it_old/4

application.ex

```
defmodule ClonerWorker.Application do
  @moduledoc false

  use Application
  import Supervisor.Spec


  def start(_type, _args) do
    genconsumer_impl = ClonerWorker
    genconsumer_group_name = "cloners"
    genconsumer_group_opts = []
    topic_names = ["todo-chunks"]

    children = [
      # this is the child that is throwing the error
      {ClonerWorker.Worker, []},
      supervisor(
        KafkaEx.ConsumerGroup,
        [genconsumer_impl,genconsumer_group_name,topic_names,genconsumer_group_opts]
      )
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: ClonerWorker.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

worker.ex

```
defmodule ClonerWorker.Worker do
  use GenServer
  use Tesla
  require Logger

  @base_url "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTradeHistory"

  def start_link(args) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, args, name:__MODULE__)
  end

  def init(args) do
    {:ok, args}
  end

  def get_history_for(currency_pair, from_unix, until_unix) do
    from_unix = from_unix * 1000
    until_unix = until_unix * 1000
    url = "#{url}&currencyPair=#{currency_pair}&start=#{from_unix}&end=#{until_unix}"
    result = send_request(url)
    if (Enum.count(result) < 1000) do
      Logger.info("Result is lesser than 1000")
      for item <- result do
        IO.inspect(item)
      end
    else
      Logger.warn("Result is greater than 1000")
    end
  end

  defp send_request(url) do
    timestamp = DateTime.to_unix(DateTime.utc_now())
    key = Application.get_env(:cloner_worker,:key)
    secret = Application.get_env(:cloner_worker,:secret)
    passphrase = Application.get_env(:cloner_worker,:passphrase)
    sign = sign(key,timestamp,url)
    headers = [{"PF-API-KEY",key},
               {"PF-API-SIGN",sign},
               {"PF-API-TIMESTAMP",timestamp},
               {"PF-API-PASSPHRASE", passphrase}]
    {:ok, result} = Tesla.get(url,headers)
    Logger.info(result.status)
    result = Jason.decode!(result.body)
  end

  defp sign(key, timestamp, endpoint, method \\ "GET", body \\ "") do
    value = "#{timestamp}#{method}#{endpoint}#{body}"
    :crypto.hmac(:sha256, key,value) |> Base.encode64
  end
end
```

i am aware that similar questions have already been asked but i couldn't find the solution for my problem there

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer me.

Comment: `Supervisor.Spec` was deprecated ages ago, why would you use it in the first place?

Comment: this is for a school project and my teacher uses it too, you can also find it in the documentation on hexdocs https://hexdocs.pm/kafka_ex/KafkaEx.ConsumerGroup.html#content

Comment: Well, if you insist on using deprecated legacy stuff, use it at least consistently everywhere: instead of `{ClonerWorker.Worker, []}` do `worker(ClonerWorker.Worker, [])`.

Comment: now i get the following error function ClonerWorker.Worker.start_link/0 is undefined
even when i change my start_link from /1 to /0 the error remains

Comment: Try to pass there something, like an empty list `worker(ClonerWorker.Worker, [[]])`. I honestly don’t remember that ancient legacy magic.

Comment: yeah i just tried it as well but the error remains but now it is complaining about start_link/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i called my file worker.exs instead of worker.ex sorry for the misunderstanding in the question where i did put worker.ex